# What is the best way to check if an object is fully defined?

Tags: javascript, string, object

The following function check if an object is defined and valorized:

```
isFullDefined(obj) => {
  return angular.isDefined(obj) && obj !== null && ("" + obj).trim() !== "";
}
```

As it is now it works, but i think that it could be improved.

For example i think that

```
("" + obj).trim() !== ""
```

could be changed with

```
String(obj).trim().length
```

but i don't know at performance level which changes are better; my thought is that

```
("" + obj)
```

could be better than

```
String(obj)
```

and that

```
mystring.length
```

is better than

```
mystring !== ""
```

Comment: "i don't know at performance level which changes are better" often means "Write a quick benchmark and find out." Run enough iterations that completing them takes >10s to reduce statistical noise. Don't just benchmark one run of each.

Comment: Is `typeof(obj) == 'string' && obj.length` too simple here?

Comment: Also you should probably use `obj != null` instead of `!==` to also catch undefined. You can get rid of angular.isDefined then.
I don't really get why you're using all this string comparison though, is `{}` a valid object in your case? Are `0` and `false`? What about `""` or `"    "`?
Are you only checking for Strings after all?

Comment: Also note this whole piece of code is probably completely irrelevant performance-wise.
You will most likely have other bottlenecks, and reducing some nanosecond snippet of it seems like premature optimization to me.

Comment: @nrausch thanks for your suggestions.
To answer your question, obj could be everything (string, boolean, object, array, etc. etc.); this function is being used only to check if the object is defined and valorized (we consider {} and [] as "valorized"); other type of check are implemented after invoking this function if necessary

Comment: [a function for timing functions](https://gist.github.com/Mellen/fdbb81ae3d835e848ea3e44fd6261035)

Comment: @P.Vucinic in that case I would suggest just using `return obj != null && (typeof obj !== 'string' || obj.length)`